# RLPx - Capability Messaging

Tags: devp2p, rlpx

I am currently having a look into the RLPx protocol and trying to understand on how two nodes exchange their capabilities.

Each subprotocol has a number of defined messages. `eth` has 12 messages (ids are `0x00 - 0x07, 0x0D - 0x10`) and `les` has 23 messages (ids are `0x00 - 0x17`). There is also `shh` and `p2p`.

RLPx is used to establish a connection between peers and after that, they are able to exchange messages from the subprotocols using the established connection.

Let's say we have two nodes who want to use the `eth` and `les` subprotocol. Both subprotocols have the status message with the id `0x00`. I am wondering how a peer knows know to with subprotocol a received status message belongs to.

I tried to read the [RLPx](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md#hello-0x00) docs but I don't understand on how this is done.